# Миграция на чип Apple M1. Проблемы с Firebase (Could not build Objective-C module ‘Firebase’, ‘FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h’ file not found) [РЕШЕНО]

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, компиляция, m1

История такая. Пользовался до недавнего времени Macbook на Intel i5, на нем мой проект запускался и работал отлично. Проект использует Google Firebase в качестве backend. Обновил ноутбук до Macbook Air M1 и Xcode до 13го и понеслось. Главная проблема на сегодняшний день это: при попытки компиляции на симулятор или девайс, появляются 2 ошибки

- ‘FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h’ file not found

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Could not build Objective-C module ‘Firebase’

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои pods, загруженные через терминал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перерыл stackoverflow, испробовал кучу вариантов, таких как

Quite xcode Delete “ProjectName.xcworkspace”, “Podfile.lock” and “Pods”. Delete project’s temp files located at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData (Command + Shift + G in finder) Run “pod install” from terminal. Open “ProjectName.xcworkspace”.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836042/error-could-not-build-objective-c-module-firebase-with-swift-5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Adding arm64 to Excluded Architectures for the main project AND for the Pods project

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171400/xcode-12-build-error-on-firanalyticsconnector/65460729#65460729

и много еще чего, но результатов нет.

Очень надеюсь, что кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным и поможет с решением.

[РЕШЕНО]: даунгрейд до Xcode 12, использовать Xcode и Terminal через Rosetta, `pod deintegrate`([по примеру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751147/remove-or-uninstall-library-previously-added-cocoapods/35316717#35316717)), установка cocoapods, `pod update`

Comment: Добавьте Firebase через SPM, а не через pods, должно помочь.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev спасибо за ответ. Можно подробнее в двух словах как установить Firebase через SPM?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods?hl=nl

Comment: @OlegSoloviev да, спасибо, уже нашел сам, но у меня почему-то не срабатывает ссылка Firebase GitHub repository (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git). Xcode пишет ошибку "Received invalid response at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git. Please make sure it is a package collection URL." Создается впечатление, что Xcode 13.1 глючный. А как установить предыдущий на macOS Monterey пока не понятно

Comment: Попробуйте .git  в конце убрать.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev спасибо, установил, но не помогло. Это какой-то кошмар. Надо было брать новый Мак на Интеле и бед не знать, угораздило же

Comment: Я пока на Big Sur и Xcode 12.5, на M1, полет нормальный. Попробуйте снести Monterey и установить Big Sur.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev я и так уже откатился на Big Sur и Xcode 12.5. Мне кажется, что я что-то принципиально делаю не так при переносе проекта с Интел на М1, по логике все должно работать. Какая комбинация настроек сработала у вас при переносе? Запуск Xcode и терминала через Розетту, обновление Pods (если да, то какими командами: arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin; sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi; arch -x86_64 pod install?), ставили arm64 в Excluded Architectures проекта и Pods? Если не сложно, поделитесь алгоритмом. Спасибо

Comment: Да в общем-то ничего особенного или специального, завелось из коробки. Были проблемы с некоторыми подами, перевёл их на SPM и всё.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev а поды у вас Firebase?

Comment: Нет, на текущих проектах нет Firebase.